# Let Android KeyStore survive factory reset

Tags: android, keystore, reset

I am generating a key using Android KeyStore, yet the key gets removed after doing factory resets.
Is there a way to avoid that?
Here's a snippet of my code:

```
if (keyStore.containsAlias(KEY_STORE_ALIAS)) {
    Log.e(TAG, "key exist");
else {
    KeyPairGenerator kpGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", "AndroidKeyStore");
    AlgorithmParameterSpec spec = null;
    spec = new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(KEY_STORE_ALIAS,
            KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
            .setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256, KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA512)
            .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_RSA_PKCS1)
            .setRandomizedEncryptionRequired(true)
            .setUserAuthenticationRequired(false)
            .build();

        kpGenerator.initialize(spec);
        KeyPair kp = kpGenerator.generateKeyPair();
        Log.e(TAG, "generate new key");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Based on Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore.html#WhichShouldIUse)

> Use the Android Keystore provider to let an individual app store its
> own credentials that only the app itself can access.

**The `KeyStore` provider instance associated with the app will be erased when you uninstall or delete the app from device.**  And, obviously during the **Factory Reset** all your installed apps will be deleted and so the `KeyStore` instance of those apps will also be erased.

So to answer your question,

> **It is impossible to retain the Keys on Factory Reset**